# Opening the settings page with return to previous page option

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-wifi, android-settings

I have an application that requires access to the Android wifi page. 
Using the code below, I was able to open the page, but there is no way to return to the previous page programatically. I don't want to use the back button on the tablet.

```
ma.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

Is there a way that I can put the settings page within an existing layout or popoup, in order that I can build a back button into the display ?

Comment: i dont think there is any way to do that

Comment: @TomerShemesh is there any other option that you think I can explore?

Comment: No i don't think there is anything you can do unfortunately. thats just how it is